# compare towers.Given the towers

Tags: c++

my code fails the tests
Ten towers are given. You need to compare them. exponentiation occurs from right to left a ^ (a ^ (a ^ a)). At the end, print their indexes in ascending order.

input:

```
10 // number of towers
4 2 2 2 2 2 // 4 The first number in a line is not an element of the tower, it is the //number of elements in it minus one. 
1 2 2
1 3 2
1 2 3
3 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
1 3 3
3 3 3 3 3
2 4 3 3
2 2 3 4
```

output:

```
2 4 3 6 7 5 9 10 1 8
```

Here is my code but it is incorrect.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class tower_t {
public:
    int num; // the tower room
    int height; // the height of the tower
    double val[11]; // content
    double cache[11]; // cache to speed up the calculation

    // Designer
    tower_t() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            val[i] = 1;
            cache[i] = 0;
        }
        height = 0;
    }

    // Triple logarithm of the top 3 levels
    double head(int level) {
        if(cache[level] == 0) cache[level] = log10(log10(val[level])) + log10(val[level + 1]) * val[level + 2];
        return cache[level];
    }

    // The calculation of the tops until intermeddle in double
    void normalize() {
        while(height > 1 && (log10(val[height - 2]) * val[height - 1]) < 50) {
            val[height - 2] = pow(val[height - 2], val[height - 1]);
            val[height - 1] = 1;
            height--;
        }
    }

    // Output for debugging
    void print() {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        printf("%2d: {", num);
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            if (i > 0) printf(", ");
            if(val[i] < 1000000000) {
                printf("%0.0f", val[i]);
            } else {
                printf("%0.3e", val[i]);
            }
        }
        printf("}\n");
#endif
    }
};

// comparison of two towers
bool compare(tower_t& t1, tower_t& t2) {
    // floor with which to compare the last three levels
    int level = ((t1.height > t2.height) ? t1.height : t2.height) - 3;
    if (level < 0) level = 0;
    if(t1.height == t2.height) { // if the towers are of the same height, compare by floor
        for (int i = t1.height - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (abs(t1.val[i] - t2.val[i]) > (t1.val[i] * 1e-14)) {
                if (i < level) { // the tops of the towers coincided below level
                    return t1.val[i] < t2.val[i];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return t1.head(level) < t2.head(level);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    // Reading job
    ifstream in ("input.txt");
    int cnt;
    in >> cnt;
    tower_t* towers = new tower_t[cnt];
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        int len;
        in >> len;
        towers[i].num = i + 1;
        bool write = true;
        for (int j = 0; j <= len; j++) {
            int val;
            in >> val;
            if (val <= 1) write = false; // if level of <= 1 the higher not to read
            if(write) {
                towers[i].val[j] = val;
                towers[i].height = j + 1;
            }
        }
        towers[i].print();
        towers[i].normalize();
    }
    // Sort
    sort(towers, towers + cnt, compare);
    // The output
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        out << towers[i].num << " ";
        towers[i].print();
    }
    out << endl;
    out.close();
    delete[] towers;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood what you are trying at all.

Comment: Please, explain the term "tower". (You didn't confuse it with "power"? Just, because you mentioned "exponentiation".)

Comment: Found [Tower (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_(mathematics)). To me, that sounds a bit like in the [Tower of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) but I still have no clue regarding your question.

Comment: you've given the output of your program but what is the expected output?

Comment: I have such a task only numbers more  https://petr-mitrichev.blogspot.com/2012/05/world-finals-day-2-upe-dinner.html

Answer (score 0):

my code does not pass this test correctly.

23

9 2 2 2 2 2 2 99 2 9 19

9 99 99 99 99 99 99 98 2 9 19

8 25 34 99 75 2 99 99 92 99

7 99 99 78 98 99 90 99 99

5 98 99 99 8 2 34

5 99 99 99 2 2 35

5 98 99 99 16 2 33

4 2 2 4 5 4

3 98 99 98 98

4 4 4 4 4 4

3 3 3 3 3

4 2 2 2 2 2

3 64 2 2 2

3 2 3 2 2

2 4 3 3

3 2 2 2 2

1 3 3

2 2 2 2

1 3 2

1 2 3

0 7

0 5

1 2 2

// correct answer

23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

//my answer

23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 1 2